# Execute url not firing for custom activity salesforce marketing cloud journey builder

Tags: journeybuilder, custom-activity

my config.json looks like this

```
{
  "workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
  "metaData": {
    "icon": "images/abc.png",
    "iconSmall": "images/abc.png"
  },
  "type": "RESTDECISION",
  "lang": {
    "en-US": {
      "name": "abc Split",
      "description": "Custom Split activity that makes a decision based on data from a custom application"
    }
  },
  
  "arguments": {
        "execute": {
            "url": url,
            "verb": "GET",
            "body": "",
            "header": "",
            "format": "json",
            "useJwt": false,
            "timeout": 100
        }
    },
  
  
  "configurationArguments": {
    "publish": {
      "url": url1
    }
  }
  ,
  "outcomes": [
    {
      "arguments": {
        "branchResult": "success"
      },
      "metaData": {
        "label": "YES"
      }
    },
    {
      "arguments": {
        "branchResult": "error"
      },
      "metaData": {
        "label": "NO"
      }
    }
  ],
  "userInterfaces": {
    "runningModal": {
      "url": "runningModal.html"
    },
    "runningHover": {
      "url": "runningHover.html"
    }
  },
  "edit": {
    "url": url2,
    "height": 200,
    "width": 500
  }
}
```

Help highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have "GET" as the method for your execute route and where are all the other routes for "validate" etc?

Comment: because I just wish to get some information back from the URL endpoint and use it for the custom split. I have tried it without even providing any info and just giving the key-value pair for the URL but still, the execute URL doesn't get triggered.